# Where is imsave in scipy 1.0.0?

Tags: python, scipy

The function `imsave()` does not exist in `scipy.misc` package in `scipy 1.0.0` (Python 3.5). Where is it?

I am trying out a [sample program](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fchollet/keras/master/examples/neural_style_transfer.py) using `keras` which in terms uses `scipy.misc.save()`. Tried searching for the alternate location all over the place, including the [index of its reference manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/genindex.html) but still can't find it.

Is there a different package that one must install to circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [this deprecation warning](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imsave.html):

> `imsave` is deprecated! `imsave` is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be
>   removed in 1.2.0. Use `imageio.imwrite` instead.

Comment: Thanks. Just found that out now. Installing `imageio` package using pip and replacing `from scipy.misc import imsave` with `from imageio import imsave` got the code working. However, is `imsave` is really the same as `imwrite`? Do you think I ought to do `import imageio.imwrite as imsave` instead?